# Optaplanner error messages using contraints.drl with Spring Boot

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using optaplanner 8.3.0 with optaplanner-spring-boot-starter, and I'm using a constraints.drl file. In previous versions, drl errors were fairly clear and had line numbers, etc.

In this configuration, I'm getting log messages like:

Typed expression Input: drlxExpr = volume , patternType = class com.drift.excelsgl.domain.planning.ExpectedTankLevel ,declarations = []

...

2021-03-17 09:01:10.397  WARN 9852 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryScheduleResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solverManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
2021-03-17 09:01:10.444 ERROR 9852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Is there a way to check the drl file that returns "the old" messages?

Comment: And when the drl file does load, I get the code generated from the drl printed what looks to be 16 times in row. It's confusing.

Comment: Yea, DRL error messages are both too verbose and too little verbose. Switch to ConstraintStreams (also uses Drools under the covers) with the latest release - those have far better error messages.

Comment: Are ConstraintStreams able to match all the constraints that  drl rules do? I did try them about a year ago and it seemed like they couldn't. Maybe it's time to try again.

Comment: Which construct where you missing? Right now, only the "consecutive n shifts in a row" is still difficult, but it's in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.` really isn't usefull indeed. Normally that should have a chained exception to that exception with the actual line number.

**Is there no actual stacktrace?** Here's what I get if I run spring-boot-school-timetabling with an invalid `constraints.drl`:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
13:27:50.462 ERROR [main           ] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'problemChangedRepositoryEventListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'timeTableController'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'timeTableController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solverManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.example.schooltimetabling.TimeTableSpringBootApp.main(TimeTableSpringBootApp.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:114)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'timeTableController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solverManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:280)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:103)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:68)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:116)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:83)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.validateSolverFactory(DefaultSolverManager.java:70)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.<init>(DefaultSolverManager.java:59)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager.create(SolverManager.java:111)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.solverManager(OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.java:98)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f11075e.CGLIB$solverManager$3(<generated>)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f11075e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ec7a757c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f11075e.solverManager(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=constraints.drl, line=1, column=0
   text=[ERR 107] Line 1:0 mismatched input 'go' expecting one of the following tokens: '[package, unit, import, global, declare, function, rule, query]'.], Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=constraints.drl, line=0, column=0
   text=Parser returned a null Package]]
    at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.getKieContainer(KieHelper.java:103)
    at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.build(KieHelper.java:82)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:272)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

Which clearly says the line number `Line 1:0 mismatched input 'go'`. How do we reproduce your case?

Comment: I mainly wanted to see if there was a way to see the error output that I'm familiar with. I can work with the output as it is. Thanks for the response.